# NG Zorro Grid component explicitly set nzSpan to auto

Tags: html, angular, responsive, ng-zorro-antd

In NG Zorro, I would like to set the raster number of span to specific value when the screen size is smaller than 768px, if it is greater than 768px, I would like to set the width to auto, this is what currently I have:

```
<div nz-row>
    <div nz-col nzXs="8" nzSm="8" nzSpan="auto">
    </div>
    <div nz-col nzXs="8" nzSm="8" nzSpan="auto">
    </div>
    <div nz-col nzXs="8" nzSm="8" nzSpan="auto">
    </div>
</div>
```

Unfortunately, this is not working as "auto" is not a valid value for nzSpan, I have tried `<div nz-col nzXs="8" nzSm="8" nzMd="auto">` still no luck. Any idea?